# Object disappears when switching to the Cycle render engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm fairly new to Blender so please forgive me if the solution is painfully obvious but I've recently been working on a model and I noticed that whenever I try to switch to the cycles render engine, some of the objects in my model disappear in the viewport and when I try to actually render them. I can see that they are still there because I can see the shadows and when I click on the area, the object itself is highlighted but I just can't see it. As I said before, I am new to Blender so I am not really sure what to do so any help would be appreciated.

[image: when rendered with Eevee]

[image: when rendered with Cycles]

Comment: Is that just the Cycles renderer, or any render? (as opposed to the viewport)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Are the objects on a different layer/ in a different collection?